# VSCode: Window to see all breakpoints and toggle them BEFORE running the debug process?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, ide

Is there a way to see all the breakpoints you set in VSCode (and toggle them) **BEFORE** running the debug process? For example, I can see the below breakpoint window, but only after already running the debug process.

[image]

Comment: By default, breakpoints are always shown (assuming you have them) in the Run and Debug tab. Just navigate there with Ctrl+Shift+D and unfold the BREAKPOINTS pane. If that does not work, it'd be helpful to evaluate more on what exactly does now work.

Answer (score 4):

Try View > Open view... > find "Breakpoints | Secondary Side Bar". You will be able to see all breakpoints and toggle them:

[Please see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hamTT.png)